# Modifying DOM of a webpage

Tags: javascript, dom

The structure of a webpage is like this :-

```
<div id='abc'>
  <div class='a'>Some contents here </div>
  <div class='b'>Some other contents< </div>
</div>
```

My aim is to add this after the class a in above structure.

```
<div class='a'>Some other contents here </div>
```

So that final structure looks like this :-

```
  <div id='abc'>
      <div class='a'>Some contents here </div>
      <div class='a'>Some other contents here </div>
      <div class='b'>Some other contents< </div>
    </div>
```

Can there be a better way to do this using DOM properties. I was thinking of naive way of parsing the content and updating.

Please comment if I am unclear in asking my doubt !

Comment: only good answer: use jquery

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you researched how to add an element to the DOM?

Comment: @trebuchet: That's just dumb.

Comment: I was trying to get the content of abc div using getELementById. Then I was parsing the content to add the value at correct position

Comment: yeah, the DOM isn't a string. It's a tree structure of nodes. After you get the parent by its id, you need to create a new element and insert it relative to one of its children.

Comment: AppendChild had an issue because I have to place it before class b

Comment: There's a method called `.insertBefore()` that lets you insert a node before one of the current children of the parent. Give that a shot.

Comment: Ok...Thanks. I will use that ! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement prepend and append with regular Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the desired element, give it the desired attributes, children, innerHTML, etc, and then append it:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('abc'),
    ele = document.createElement('div');

ele.setAttribute('class', 'a');
ele.innerHTML = "Some other contents here";

parent.appendChild(ele);​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmXNX/1)

You can be lazy and just set the `innerHTML` of `#abc`, but in my opinion this method is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/cExRS/
The code is this one

```
element = document.getElementById('abc');
element.innerHTML = "<div class='a'>Some other contents here </div>" + element.innerHTML;
```

You should really try jquery, it makes things a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Liked pointed out there's answer for prepending, [Insert sibling node in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771921/insert-sibling-node-in-js)
and [How can I implement prepend and append with regular JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(myClass) {
    var root = document.getElementById('abc');
    var last = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = root.childNodes[i];
        if (!child.className) continue;        
        var pat = new RegExp(myClass,'g');    
        var m = pat.exec(child.className);      
        if (!m) {
          if (!last) continue;
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('After A content'));    
            root.insertBefore(div, last.nextSibling);        
            break;            
        }
        last = child;                     
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='abc'>
  <div class='d'>Some contents here </div>
  <div class='b'>Some other contents </div>
  <div class='a'>Content A</div>
  <div class='a'>Content A1</div>
  <div class='a'>Content A2</div>
  <div class='a'>Content A3</div>
  <div class='b'>Some other contents </div>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="add('a')">Add div</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate :s

[How can I implement prepend and append with regular JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript)

It's called prepending

Comment: Why the down vote? The answer is there. Just trying to help over here

Comment: This is better off as a comment