# Non-invasive Javascript HTML injection

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a non-invasive javascript HTML/CSS/JS injection into page.
I'm ideally looking to use document.write, but keep the original contents that were on the page. So doing the following:

javascript:document.write("blablabla"); - this removes all the content on page, I don't want to use innerHTML += to append the data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write`. Use `document.createElement` to create new elements, use the `document.getElement*` functions to query for parent elements to which you'd like to append. Then use that element's `appendChild` function to add your new elements.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid createElement.

Comment: Why would you avoid `createElement`?

Answer (score -1):

If document.write is called after the onload event for the document it needs to re-open the document - effectively truncating it. While you can explicitly call document.write() inline (either with javascript directly embedded in the page or with a  tag which does not use defer/async) this is considered bad practice as it blocks all the other processing of the page.

You can [inject elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771921/insert-sibling-node-in-js) by [constructing them in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) personally I prefer to set the innerHTML of an existing placeholder to an HTML fragment:

```
<div id='placeholder/></div>
...
document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML="<h2>hello world!</h2>";
```

(using createElement becomes messy and slow when creating/injecting complex HTML)

Answer (score -2):

document.write will always overwrite the whole page as far I know. One option is to append/prepend your code to a div or to the bottom of your body.

```
$(elementObj).append(contents);
//or
$(elementObj).prepend(contents);
```

You can createElement() then use one of the methods above to inject your code into the newly created element.